# Android Tablet (4.0.3) home icon (lower left corner of the action bar) does not work when clicked

Tags: home-button

Alright, so I am having trouble with my brandless tablet. It's running on Android 4.0.3. When I click the home button in the lower-left part of the screen, action bar, nothing happens. The button looks like a "house". I have tried resetting the device, but it doesn't help. I have no idea on what to do as I am a "noob" when it comes to Android. Please help me out with whatever you can, thank you.

Comment: Where are you when "nothing happens"? Could it be you are simply on your homescreen? Then it's normal that nothing happens, as that button should bring you exactly to where you are then. Try tapping it when you have another app in the foreground, and see what happens then: you should be returned to your *home*screen (hence the "house" aka "home" symbol).

Comment: I know what the button is supposed to do. And no, I click it when I am in an application (Internet for an example). I tap the button, hold it, click it, whatever you can think of, and nothing happens. The button just flashes like normal, but doesn't bring me to the home screen. Further help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, Nikola -- no offense meant. You didn't include that fact with your question, but rather referred to "noob" -- so I had to expect the worst :) Of course, in this case that's not the expected behaviour. As it "flashes", it seems to register your touch. If it happens just with one app, this app might "catch" the intent somehow (as could be the case with any other app running at that time). As you have reset the device, and it happened even before you installed anything (?), I'd consult the shop where you've bought it, or call the service.

Comment: It happens with every application, not just one. When I bought the device, the button was working properly for about months, until one day, it was at a tech. to change the screen(It had a crack, so it had to be changed). Ever since then, the button isn't working. I will call the tech. tomorrow, and ask him if he had done something. IF you have any other ideas, please feel free to type them down. Thank You. :)

Comment: Ah, that sheds some light. I am not sure (as I'm not in assembling), but might be he forgot some contact or attached something wrongly. So the response you see is just from the touchscreen itself, not from the "soft button", so to speak. Good idea to talk to the very same tech, he should know! // Btw: If he can solve it (or you can otherwise achieve a solution), feel free to answer your question yourself (and accept the answer after two days, which is the earliest you can do so for your own answer) -- so others can see this problem has a solution attached :)

Comment: Alright, I'll get in touch with him tomorrow, thank you for your time. And sure, if I get it fixed, I'll make my answer the solution.

Comment: Did the issue solve meanwhile?